# JSON from Reddit

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Is it even possible to get JSON feed from Reddit and post it in my site. I've tried in two ways, both do not seem to work.

**First approach**

```
$.getJSON('http://www.reddit.com/.json?feed=HASH_HERE&user=USER_HERE', function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Output

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.reddit.com/.json?feed=HASH_HERE&user=USER_HERE. Origin http://localhost:14102 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

**Second approach**

```
var url = "http://www.reddit.com/.json?feed=HASH_HERE&user=USER_HERE";
$.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function (data) {
   alert(data);
});
```

Output

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is cross-domain issue. Reddit is giving the result as json format which is only not enough for making cross-domain request using getJSON like the second option.

Please check the below one for flickr web service,

```
<script>
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
  {
    tags: "cat",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  },
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
      if ( i == 3 ) return false;
    });
  });</script>
```

[Ref url](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for url for the above code.

Please check this [site](http://www.pacecode.com/blog/2011/09/01/cross-domain-communications-with-jsonp-using-javascript-and-jquery/), they have given real time example for the cross-domain request.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a server-side script on your site to fetch it, and get your json from that script in your javascript, because of the Same Origin Policy.

Further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy